# Multiplication & checkboxes value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Now I have a little problem with my code.

I have a questionnaire, with radio button answers. Their value is a coefficient. All recorded in Mongodb.

Here is my html code:

```
<!--réponses-->
<div ng-repeat="r in q.reponses" class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="radio" data-placement="bottom-left">
        <label class="radio" id="labelRep" for="{{r.coefficient}}">
            <input type="radio" ng-change="updateCounter(r.coefficient)" ng-model="reponseQuestionnaire.userAnswers[r.code]" value="{{r.coefficient}}" id="{{r.coefficient}}" class="custom-checkbox"/>
                {{r.reponse}}
        </label>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Whatever I want:

I would like to multiply the coefficients corresponding to the ticked answers.

Do you know a function?

I tried this function in my controller but without success :

```
$scope.counter = 0;

$scope.updateCounter = function ($event, coefficient, value){
        coefficient = parseInt(coefficient, 10);
        if (value === 0) {
            $scope.counter += coefficient;
        }
        else{
            $scope.counter -= coefficient;
        }
```

Thank you in advance.

Yours sincerely.

Please note that the techno I use is AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-change`'s first param is whatever you pass to its calling function not `$event`.

change this

`$scope.updateCounter = function ($event, coefficient, value)`

to

`$scope.updateCounter = function (coefficient)`

and the function will be called properly.

Comment: ok, thank you..! and for the function ? Do you have an idea ?

Comment: @Nadjeem  what function?

Comment: for processing, what is the function? What does it contain? If I remove "value" in parameters, I have "value is not defined"...

Comment: @Nadjeem you have not used the value in your code!!!! what value suppose to be? where its value comes from???

Comment: The value comes from mongodb, via a"get"method, the "ng-repeat" allows me to retrieve my questions and answers, each answer has a coefficient, and in the html I retrieve the coefficient like this: value="{{r. coefficient}}".

Comment: @Nadjeem dude you are not providing any code samples!! I don't see value in your code! where `value` has been defined ???? so I can't tell you how to use it!!! It's not magic, define a function with some params, pass those params to the function when you use that function, use the params inside the function!!!

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to following

**Html**

```
ng-change="updateCounter(r.coefficient,value)"`
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.updateCounter = function (coefficient, value){
    coefficient = parseInt(coefficient, 10);
    if (value === 0) {
        $scope.counter += coefficient;
    }
    else{
        $scope.counter -= coefficient;
    }
```

Comment: thank you ! but that reminds me NaN.. Do you have any idea where that might come from?

Comment: That might be because value sending from html is undefined so set it to zero in controller

Comment: Where does that value come from because you have not specified it anywhere in html or in controller except the comdition

Comment: The value comes from mongodb, via a"get"method, the "ng-repeat" allows me to retrieve my questions and answers, each answer has a coefficient, and in the html I retrieve the coefficient like this: value="{{r. coefficient}}".

Comment: Then change the html to ng-change="updateCounter(r.coefficient,r.value)"